# How to insert big json file into postgresql

Tags: python, json, windows, postgresql, memory-management

i have a big json file (9 gb), which contains a list of more or less 950k nested dicts (this was generated in python), they are separated by commas and have this structure overall:

```
{'orderId': 111,
 'dateCreated': '2019-03-06 16:00:12',
 'Customer': {'customerCode': 222,
  'customerName1': 'NAME',
  'deliveryPostCode': '332',
  'deliveryAddress': 'Street 5',
  'deliveryCity': 'Any'},
 'Products': [{'delivery': '3323',
   'productCode': 2221,
   'quantity': 1.0,
   'unitOfMeasure': 'Kilo',
   'packNum': '3232',
   'prodFam': 222},
  {'delivery': '554',
   'productCode': 223321,
   'quantity': 1.0,
   'unitOfMeasure': 'Kilo',
   'packNum': '3232',
   'prodFam': 222},
  {'delivery': '332',
   'productCode': 222,
   'quantity': 1.0,
   'unitOfMeasure': 'Kilo',
   'packNum': '3232',
   'prodFam': 222}]}
```

I want to import every dict of that in a table of postgre, let's say:

```
CREATE TABLE orders (orders jsonb);
```

The problem is, my computer have 16gb of RAM but i am unable to import it into postgre using:

```
sql> \set content `type C:\test\dict.json`
sql> insert into orders values (:'content');
```

It fails with error:

```
type C:\test\dict.json: exhausted memory
```

How i can do that import by chunk size? I know i can do that using cat command from linux, but in windows i don't know how to.
I wanted to do this directly into postgre, because by doing via python i came across memory problems as well.

I am using windows 10 and Postgre 13.2

Thank you!

Comment: Why do you want to put 9GB of json into a single column of a single row? I'm struggling to figure out what you would do with it then. I mean, you'll never be able to read it back out and do anything with it, will you? Not with only 16GB of RAM

Comment: @RichardHuxton actually i wanted to put every dict in one row, not all of them in one

Comment: But your SQL is treating them as a single row, isn't it? Why bother with the file anyway - why not just insert the data into the db from the python as it generates it?

Answer (score 0):

There is a hard limit of 1GB for a data item in PostgreSQL, but you are likely to become unhappy even before that limit.

These data are tabular data in a JSON format. So define appropriate tables (without using a JSON data type), unwrap the JSON on the client side and `INSERT` the data into the tables.